# What's the best way to maintain two different monitor profiles, one for web and one for print?

Tags: color-management

As far as I've read, for different purposes the monitor can be calibrated using diffeent color profiles characterised by different color temperatures (e.g. D65 for Web, D50-55 for photo/print).

I am interested to know the best approach to make this happen,

- having as starting point the *reset to default* monitor settings applying software calibration values (D65/D50-55), OR
- in two steps:

  1. using the hardware monitor manual color control to adjust the colors at the desired value (let's say 6500K) and after that
  2. applying the software compensation

The second does not seem like a great method, taking in consideration the fact that we need two different profiles and we have to change manually the settings.

Answer (score 2):

You should *not* be using different profiles for your monitor for different output purposes.

The monitor should be calibrated and profiled with a colorimeter or spectrophotometer. This will allow the monitor to display the best and most-correct color it is capable of.

Then, you should soft proof to your output device: that may be sRGB for web output, or a specific printer for paper output.

This is a fundamental beginning to using color management effectively, so I recommend you familiarize yourself with some reading: [Color Management & Quality Output: Working with Color from Camera to Display to Print](http://amzn.com/0240821114) and [Real World Color Management](http://amzn.com/0321267222) are great places to start.

Comment: Excellent point. And for print, download specific ICC profiles for different papers which are usually available from the manufacturer website. When printing, always disable color management in the images and select the correct profile for your printer. It happens frequently where ICC profiles are doubled up resulting in very undesirable results.

Comment: Err, the question is not about different output device profile, but about color temperature. Softproofing for sRGB or for your printers's profile won't change the color temperature (when printing, the color temperature has nothing to do with the printer, it's the color of the ambient light when viewing the prints).

Answer (score 0):

I'd just make sure my monitor was adjusted for the best and widest gamut for all work.

Web images will be coerced to Adobe RGB because that is a widely supported standard and you have no control at all in how Web user agents render your images beyond hints.

As for print, you should soft proof if it matters. Everything, from the paper type, paper finish, printer type, etc., are going to impact the final product.

It's not recommended that you tweak the monitor where you do post work to match the final rendition. Work with the widest, truest gamut you can and tune the renditions for the appropriate use as a last step.

Comment: thank you for your feed-back; I agree with you regarding the screen-to-print process, there are multiple varible. _adjusted for the best and widest gamut_ compared with what? Do you still use a hardware color display calibrator?

Comment: Yeah, I'd just use a colorimeter and adjust the monitor so that it gives you some notion of accurate response. A monitor will always respond differently than reflective media like prints, and images on the web will be a fraction of possible gamut, and subject to user agent interpretation.